# Solve an equation with Laplacian

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I want to solve the following exercise:

[image]

Did I calculate this well?
How can I physically interpret this result? And what other functions of theta can the result be generalized?

My resolution:

[image]

The solution of the book:
[image]

Comment: you have to type `Cos` function 
correctly: `3*Cos[\[theta]]^2-1`

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Your command is giving me an error in my code.

Comment: The questions about "physically interpreting this result" and "what other functions of theta can the result be generalized [to]" are probably better suited for Mathematics StackExchange;  I would encourage you to ask a separate question over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
Solve[Laplacian[f[r, \[Theta]]*(3 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 - 1), {r, \[Theta]},
  "Polar"] == g[r] (3 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 - 1), g[r]] // 
Together // FullSimplify
```

[image]

by applying:

[image]

it reduces to

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It already works. Do you know what theta values the function can be generalized for?

Comment: What command can I use to appear the reduced formula that appeared at the end?

Comment: Just use rules to substitute

Comment: I put the resolution of the book in the post, but with its Mathematica program I am not giving the same solution and I have already tried to move to Cartesian coordinates. How can I get to the book solution?

Answer (score 1):

The coordinate chart `"Polar"` is reserved for 2D polar coordinates in Mathematica.  For 3D spherical coordinates, use the coordinate chart `"Spherical"` instead:

```
Simplify[Solve[ 
   Laplacian[f[r] (3 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 - 1), {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"] 
   == g[r] (3 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 - 1), g[r]]]

(* {{g[r] -> -(6 f[r])/r^2 + (2 Derivative[1][f][r])/r + Derivative[2][f][r]}} *)
```

This is precisely the result you cite from your textbook.

Information about Mathematica's built-in coordinate systems, including a list of the ones it knows about, can be found on the [CoordinateChartData documentation page.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateChartData.html)

Comment: Oh, nowhere is indicated to work in spherical coordinates. I solved it before the boom solution was posted.